# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Long

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0

I am trying to create a named-native-query that returns a Long.

Here is my orm.xml file (simplified as much as possible)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">

<named-native-query name="getCaseNumberByCommId" result-class="java.lang.Long">
  <query>SELECT case_id FROM communications WHERE comm_id =(?1)</query>
</named-native-query>

</entity-mappings>
```

this is the error I get:

ERROR - org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - Error in named query: getCaseNumberByCommId
[coral:launch] org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Long

I've also tried just specifying "Long"

```
<named-native-query name="getCaseNumberByCommId" result-class="Long">
  <query>SELECT case_id FROM communications WHERE comm_id =(?1)</query>
</named-native-query>
```

and strangely get this error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to find entity-class: Long
...
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Long

Java can't find Long in java.lang?

Thank you for any clues

**edit**:  I tried removing the 'result-class' annotation :

```
    <named-native-query name="getCaseNumberByCommId" >
        <query>SELECT case_id FROM communications WHERE comm_id =(?1)</query>
    </named-native-query>
```

and get this error:

nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported

***Update****

I never did find a way to do this, but since the database had a uniqueness constraint on comm_id, I was able to just return a mapped pojo object instead of a count.

e.g.

```
    <named-native-query name="getByCommId" result-class="com.foo.model.Communication">
        <query>SELECT * FROM communications WHERE comm_id =(?1)</query>
    </named-native-query>
```

and then pull the desired case_id out of the returned pojo.

Answer (score 13):

Without looking into this further the `result-class` should be one of your mapped entities
and because `Long` is not one of your Entities you're receiving the `AnnotationException`.

Try removing the `result-class` from the mapping as it is only used for building queries that return `Entity` Objects.

---

**Edit:**

> In regard to: `org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported`:

After a quick dig around I found this:

> [https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-661](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/ANN-661)

Where I read:

> Workaround is to do such queries using Session.createSQLQuery() or straight JDBC.

There are a couple of examples for such queries here:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17378

i.e

> `sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM CATS").list();`
>
> `sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS").list();`

or further down in `Example 18.4`
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#querysql-namedqueries

```
<sql-query name="mySqlQuery">
    <return-scalar column="name" type="string"/>
    <return-scalar column="age" type="long"/>
    SELECT p.NAME AS name, 
           p.AGE AS age,
    FROM PERSON p WHERE p.NAME LIKE 'Hiber%'
</sql-query>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried removing the result-class annotation and get this error:  nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported

Comment: @slashdottir Did any of the extra information help you out or did you solve it another way?

Comment: I finally had to give up on returning a Long and wound up returning a mapped pojo object instead....  Since it turned out that in the database there is a uniqueness constraint which means only 1 row per identifier, I was able to work around this problem in this way

Answer (score 1):

```
<named-native-query name="getCaseNumberByCommId">
  <query>SELECT case_id FROM communications WHERE comm_id =(?1)</query>
</named-native-query>
```

something like this works for me.